# Get an exception once divide two values

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am retrieving two values from a database, and need to divide them, but it gives me null pointer exception on line 1 and 2

```
1    int value1 = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("value1"));
2    int value2 = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("value2"));
3    double result = (double)value1/value2;


Error 

 java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
```

Comment: did you print rs.getString("value1") and found that it is not null?

Comment: and secondly did you try out to see if the return values were actually integers?

Comment: One of the two values has returned null from `rs.getString` and the `Integer.parseInt` doesn't know how it should be formatted.  If possible use `rs.getInt(...)`, assuming the column value is actually a number

Answer (score 1):

That is because, you are getting a `null` value from your database, that you cannot pass to `Integer.parseInt()`.

If one of the `res.getString("value1");`, or `res.getString("value2")` is `null`, you will get an exception.

A better way is to wrap that conversion around `try-catch` block, and in `catch` block print the value of `res.getString("value1")`; to check the actual value returned.

**EDIT**: -

Of course, you can also first print the value returned before you convert it to `integer` to find if that is `null` or not.

Comment: Actually, it would be better to check the return result for null over relying on a exception trap to do the validation, after all, an exception is, well an exception to the expected...+1 however for the every thing before that

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah that is true, but that is just to make OP find out why exception occur. But your point is correct to. Will Edit :)

Comment: :D sorry, just begin picky ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Ah! That's no problem at all. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int value1 = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("value1"));
int value2 = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("value2"));
```

this line must be giving null thats why its giving null pointer exception

Comment: Why can't the second line be returning null...?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse only integer values which are in the form of Strings. For e.g. :

```
 int i = Integer.parseInt("20");
 int j = Integer.parseInt("NaN"); // throws NumberFormatException
```

Also, you should check values for `null` to avoid `NPE` as :

```
int v1=0, v2=0;
String value1 = rs.getString("value1");
if(value1  != null) {
    v1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
}
String value2 = rs.getString("value2");
if(value1  != null) {
    v2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do...

```
double result = 0;

String value1 = rs.getString("value1");
String value2 = rs.getString("value2");
if (value1 != null && value2 != null) {
    try {
        result = (double)(Integer.parseInt(value1) / (double)Integer.parseInt(value2))
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
      // Handle or re-throw exception...
    }
}
return result;
```

Or, if the column values are actually numbers...

```
double result = 0;

int value1 = rs.getInt("value1");
int value2 = rs.getInt("value2");

if (result2 > 0) {
    result = (double)value1 / (double)value2;
}
return result;
```

Or, which might be simpler

```
double result = 0;

int value1 = rs.getDouble("value1");
int value2 = rs.getDouble("value2");

if (result2 > 0) {
    result = value1 / value2;
}
return result;
```